# Using results of one query to filter the next

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have 3 tables UserInfo, Class & ClassAttendance.

I am trying to combine two queries so that i can update my user info

my first query searches the course table for courses within a date range

```
Select ClassID from Class 
Where ClassDate > '04/23/2018'
```

My second query updates information based on the amount of times a member has attended a class

```
update UserInfo 
SET ParticipationStatus = 'standard participant'
where (
select count(MemberID)
from ClassAttendance
WHERE UserInfo.MemberID=ClassAttendance.MemberID

) >= 4
```

I'm assuming using a Join would be the best way but I can't figure it out

Comment: What does "combine two queries" mean?  Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: Have you tried with merge statement? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: Your queries seem fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of output you expecting, if need of join just check if below query will help:

```
update UserInfo 
SET ParticipationStatus = 'standard participant'
where (SELECT count(ClassAttendance.MemberID) as MEM_cnt
from ClassAttendance
join UserInfo
on UserInfo.MemberID=ClassAttendance.MemberID) > =4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pl/sql:

```
begin

for x in (select ClassID from Class 
                 where ClassDate > '04/23/2018')
loop
   for y in (select MemberID, count(ClassId) as Member_count from ClassAttendance
                    where ClassId = x.Class group by MemberId having count(ClassId) >=4 )
   loop
        update UserInfo SET ParticipationStatus = 'standard participant' where MemberID = y.MemberId;
   end loop;
end loop;

end;
```